# How to add an event to a Custom Control in Lotus Domino XPages?

Tags: lotus, lotus-domino, xpages

I'm developing an Lotus XPages solution. I have a Custom Control that I would like to have additional functionality in the form of an event call-back.

Is it possible to create a JavaScript callback or event in a custom control? What I'd really like is to add events to one of my controls, something like OnSomething or querySomething and postSomething, so that when the event is fired, the code at the calling end is properly called.

Can it be done??

Thanks!

Comment: [This blog post](http://lotusnotus.com/lotusnotus_en.nsf/dx/lesson-of-the-day-i-need-to-learn-more-about-xpages.htm) describes a way to add an event to a custom control.

Comment: Pass a function as a java.lang.Object? Not a bad idea, at all!